# Android change timezone, time and date

Tags: android, date, time, timezone

I want to programtically set date, time and timezone in android. Is it possible. There are conflicting answers where some say is it possible and others say it is not possible.

Comment: Have you tried http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html#setid method?

Answer (score 1):

It is posible. But you can start default system DateTimeSettingsSetupWizard.

```
int requestCode = 101; //any number
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.DateTimeSettingsSetupWizard");
try {
    startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
}
catch(ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "startNewActivity - Not found Activity");
}
```

Comment: I think you mean "it is impossible" for a normal app (without root privileges).  I like that you suggest launching the wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Surely the following class can do it?
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html

## LOCATION:

java.lang.Object
   ↳    java.util.Date

## CONSTRUCTOR:

public Date (int year, int month, int day)
Constructs a new Date initialized to midnight in the default TimeZone on the specified date.
Parameters
year    the year, 0 is 1900.
month   the month, 0 - 11.
day     the day of the month, 1 - 31.

## ALSO TRY USING:

As date class is deprecated in some instances, try using: 
GregorianCalendar(int, int, int)